# Give all entries from a particular position in Redis

Tags: redis

I have following table:

```
| timestamp  | user   | count |
|------------|--------|-------|
| 1432888700 | muster | 2     |
| 1432888699 | muster | 1     |
| 1432888693 | muster | 2     | <-- position
| 1432888692 | muster | 1     |
```

in Redis i could add this values with following command:

```
hset muster 1432888692 1
hset muster 1432888693 2
hset muster 1432888699 1
```

All the entries are sorted by the timestamp. Now I want to output all the entries of a specific position. For example in SQL-Syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM muster WHERE timestamp >= 1432888693
```

I not really found the specified commands in redis to do that. Do you know the command or this is at all possible in Redis?

Comment: What does it means "all the entries of a specific position"? Give an example.

Comment: I add an example in SQL-Syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible provided you use the right data structure. In your example, you used a hash object, which does not store the items in an ordered way.

You may want to use a sorted set instead (see the [Zxxx commands](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set)), and just use the timestamp as a score.

```
ZADD muster 1432888692 1
ZADD muster 1432888693 2
ZADD muster 1432888699 1
```

To find records whose timestamp is greater or equal to a specific value, you can then use [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore):

```
#  WHERE timestamp >= 1432888693
ZRANGEBYSCORE muster 1432888693 +inf WITHSCORES
```

Comment: This example works, but when I add a further entry, then the items will be overwritten by the new entry. For example i add the new entry (ZADD muster 1432888700 2), then the entry with the timestamp 1432888693 will be deleted. So the range (ZRANGEBYSCORE muster 1432888693 +inf WITHSCORES) would be output as follows:  1. 1432888699  1   2.   1432888700  2  but i want also the entry 1432888693 2. How can i do that?

Comment: A sorted set is a set, so all items are unique. One trick you can use is to concatenate the timestamp to the count. ZADD muster timestamp count:timestamp This way, you ensure each item is unique.